# "Waiting for a map" when building a map from a bag file but nothing happens

Tags: navigation, ros, robotics, realsense, slam

I am trying to build a map using slam and I followed this tutorial [SLAM with D435i](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/wiki/SLAM-with-D435i). But when I run map server to save the map I receive a massage that saying "Waiting for a map" but nothing seems to be happening. And also I followed almost all the Q&A regarding this issue. This [Question on ROS Answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/222327/problem-with-building-a-map-from-a-bag-file/) might seems relevant to this question and answere but didn't work for me. I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** and **Ros Melodic**. And also I am using realsence camera to create the bag file.

Here is the Ros topics list after executing the required topics.

- /base_scan
- /clock
- /map
- /map_metadata
- /rosout
- /rosout_agg
- /slam_gmapping/entropy
- /tf
- /tf_static

And also I have the node info of slam_gmapping.[image: Node info slam_gmapping]

Source code of the real_sense launch file.

```
    <launch>
    <arg name="offline"          default="false"/>
    <include unless="$(arg offline)"
        file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/rs_camera.launch">
        <arg name="align_depth" value="true"/>
        <arg name="linear_accel_cov" value="1.0"/>
        <arg name="unite_imu_method" value="linear_interpolation"/>
    </include>

    <node pkg="imu_filter_madgwick" type="imu_filter_node" name="ImuFilter">
        <param name="use_mag" type="bool" value="false" />
        <param name="_publish_tf" type="bool" value="false" />
        <param name="_world_frame" type="string" value="enu" />
        <remap from="/imu/data_raw" to="/camera/imu"/>
    </node>

    <include file="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/rtabmap.launch">
        <arg name="args" value="--delete_db_on_start"/>
        <arg name="rgb_topic" value="/camera/color/image_raw"/>
        <arg name="depth_topic" value="/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw"/>
        <arg name="camera_info_topic" value="/camera/color/camera_info"/>
        <arg name="depth_camera_info_topic" value="/camera/depth/camera_info"/>
        <arg name="rtabmapviz" value="false"/>
        <arg name="rviz" value="true"/>
    </include>

    <include file="$(find robot_localization)/launch/ukf_template.launch"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/frequency" value="300"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/base_link_frame" value="camera_link"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/odom0" value="rtabmap/odom"/>
    <rosparam param="/ukf_se/odom0_config">[true,true,true,
                                            true,true,true,
                                            true,true,true,
                                            true,true,true,
                                            true,true,true]
    </rosparam>
    <param name="/ukf_se/odom0_relative" value="true"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/odom0_pose_rejection_threshold" value="10000000"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/odom0_twist_rejection_threshold" value="10000000"/>
</rosparam>
    <param name="/ukf_se/imu0_differential" value="true"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/imu0_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="/ukf_se/use_control" value="false"/>
    <!-- <param name="/ukf_se/odom0_config" value="{true,true,true,}"/> -->
</launch>
```

[PDF generated by tf view_frames](https://gofile.io/d/kbB8nS)

A help is appreciated a lot. Thank you.

Comment: After run intended lunch files, could you type "rostopic list" in the terminal and put send us the output

Comment: @GPrathap I updated the question. Would you mind taking a look at it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you launched realsense  camera lunch file? there is o topic for that? Please add lunch files you have executed as well

Comment: @GPrathap I updated the question with the real sense launch file. Thank you very much for your concern. I used this link to get the launch file if it is helpful. https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros

Comment: if you run relase lunch file you should see /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw as a topic

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I think the problem is I cannot subscribe the sensor message/laser scan from the base scan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220194/discussion-between-gprathap-and-kalanachinthaka).